# use CASE statement and QUOTENAME together

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, case

I am facing a SQL query issue with SQL Server.

I have a query something like this.

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(A, '"'),
 QUOTENAME(B, '"'),
 QUOTENAME(C, '"')

FROM TABLENAME
```

Now, I have to replace this with a CASE statement.

Now this query works -

```
SELECT A,
CASE
WHEN B='Thank you' then 'TY'
WHEN B='No Problem' then 'NP'
WHEN B='As soon as possible' then 'ASAP'
END AS B,
C
FROM TABLENAME
```

Now I am using QUOTENAME because I want to enclose the fields with double quotes. Any possible scenario how I can mix both QUOTENAME and the CASE statements. SO far whatever I have tried throws a syntax error.

Comment: Just use `SELECT QUOTENAME(CASE WHEN ..... WHEN ..... END, '"') as B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should simply work like this

```
SELECT A,
       CASE
         WHEN B='Thank you' then QUOTENAME('TY', '"')
         WHEN B='No Problem' then QUOTENAME('NP', '"')
         WHEN B='As soon as possible' then QUOTENAME('ASAP', '"')
       END AS B,
       C
FROM TABLENAME
```

or much shorter

```
SELECT A,
       QUOTENAME( CASE
                    WHEN B='Thank you' then 'TY'
                    WHEN B='No Problem' then 'NP'
                    WHEN B='As soon as possible' then 'ASAP'
                  END, '"') AS B,
       C
FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Thanks @GuidoG . It worked great! And, now when I see your query, I can understand what I was doing wrong. I am so damn silly at times.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a little bit shorter too compared to GuidoG solution:

```
SELECT A
  , QUOTENAME(CASE B
                  WHEN 'Thank you' THEN 'TY'
                  WHEN 'No Problem' THEN 'NP'
                  WHEN 'As soon as possible' THEN 'ASAP'
              END, '"') AS B
  , C
FROM TABLENAME;
```

If you're always comparing a single column for equality, you can just write `CASE COLUMN_NAME` and then do comparisons like that: `WHEN 1 THEN 'LOL1' WHEN 2 THEN 'LOL2'` and etc.